# In Rust, is there a function for continuously "folding" a stream, i.e. mapping with state?

Tags: rust

I have a futures::stream::Stream of websocket messages that represent state changes, and I want a stream of the state. I've come across the `fold` method which does something similar, but it collects everything up into one final state, rather than producing a new stream of all the intermediate states.

E.g. I have an initial state "0" and a stream of "increment" and "decrement" events, I want a stream of the resulting numbers.

Comment: I'm only just starting to learn Rust so I can't be confident of how to use it, but having a background in functional programming and having searched the documentation, it looks like the [scan](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) method could be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Robin Zigmond mentioned in the comments, the [`Iterator::scan`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea1b40c8f3691833af71dfaa6387867c) function is probably what you're looking for.

Example:

```rust
/// Our "event" type, with increment and decrement events.
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Event {
    Inc,
    Dec,
}

/// For simplicity, the `Event::apply` function will modify our integer
/// depending on the event.
impl Event {
    fn apply(&self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Inc => n + 1,
            Dec => n - 1,
        }
    }
}

/// Import `Event::Inc` and `Event::Dec` into scope so we can access them as
/// simply `Inc` and `Dec`.
use Event::{Inc, Dec};

fn main() {
    // List of events
    let events = &[ Inc, Inc, Dec, Inc, Dec, Dec ];

    let values: Vec<_> = events.iter().scan(0i32, |n, ev| {
        // `n` is a mutable reference to the "state" of the scan.
        // It initially has the value `0i32`, but we can modify it each time
        // the closure is called.
        *n = ev.apply(*n);

        // The closure can return `Some(expr)`, which is the next value of the
        // iterator, or `None` to end early. In our case we just return the state.
        Some(*n)
    }).collect();

    println!("events = {:?}", events); // [Inc, Inc, Dec, Inc, Dec, Dec]
    println!("values = {:?}", values); // [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0]
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5fbcc1436dca106e26eb46c236f8cfbe)

Answer (score 1):

In the `Iterator` world, [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) would be the appropriate adapter for this job. But a `Stream` is not an `Iterator`, so we can't use `Iterator`'s methods.

The [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) trait provides extension methods for the [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) trait. Many of these methods are adapted versions of `Iterator`'s adapter methods. This includes [`scan`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.scan).